# Issue with cell navigation in Excel from Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small project to get data from Access using SQL queries and write the data into an excel. In preparation for that, I tried to do the following. The resulting output is "Hello" in (6,5) and "Hello Again" in (6,6). The "World" gets lost.  I am little unsure how to navigate correctly. Most of the other variables that you see below are declared global.

```
Sub enterDataInCell()

Dim Cell As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("H:\Documents\Misc-Work\BU\test.xlsx")

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

irow = 6
icol = 5

Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol)

Cell.Value = "Hello"

Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol).offset(0, 1)

Cell.Value = "World"

Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol).offset(0, 1)

Cell.Value = "Hello Again"

wb.Save
wb.Close
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

Set wb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set Cell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: it's because you rewrote "World" with "Hello again". At first you writes in (6,6)="World" and then (6,6)="Hello again"

Comment: doesn't the offset move it over 1 column? If not what do I need to do to see the 3 words?

Comment: You need `.Offset(0,2)` for the second offset statement...

Comment: @user3245460, offset moves over one column from `cells(irow, icol)` each time and gets the same cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the value of `iCol` hasn't changed (and will not change, no matter how many times you use the `.Offset` method, you need to change the argument sent to the `.Offset` method.

Try:

```
Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol)

Cell.Value = "Hello"

Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol).offset(0, 1)

Cell.Value = "World"

Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol).offset(0, 2)

Cell.Value = "Hello Again"
```

Or you can explicitly refer to the row/column position and avoid `.Offset` altogether:

```
Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol)

Cell.Value = "Hello"

Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol + 1)

Cell.Value = "World"

Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol + 2)

Cell.Value = "Hello Again"
```

Alternatively, you can define the `Cell` object, and then set it as a new cell using the `Offset` method.

```
Set Cell = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Activesheet.cells(irow, icol)

Cell.Value = "Hello"

Set Cell = Cell.offset(0, 1)

Cell.Value = "World"

Set Cell = Cell.offset(0, 1)

Cell.Value = "Hello Again"
```

Comment: Instead of that complicated construct of `= xlApp.Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet...` try using just your worksheet variable, which presumably did not raise an error: `Set cell = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol)`